# Partially download file with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, download

I am new to javascript. I made a python program to download files and, in case of connection failure, the program can resume the file download. But doesn't work me in my college due the proxy that doesn't let me make connections from another program other than a web browser.

The fact is that I can not put downloading files from firefox, for example, because after a while the connection drops, so I'm thinking of doing the same thing I did in python, but with javascript.

I spent the week looking for some way to partially download a file and store it in a variable. for example ... If I have a `URL = http: //www.example.com/blabla/movie.mkv` as I can create a connection or download 128KB chunks, for example? then send it to a file.

And... How can I continue a download from some byte to end? (like add the header `Range=1024-`)

I tried with `XMLHttpRequest`, but I can not download files in two different domains (CORS)

Comment: You could fake your Python script's user agent to have the proxy see it as a web browser request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could not do that using JavaScript, because of CORS rules.

Actually you could disable these rules when writing code for Firefox add-on for example ([Firefox SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides))

But your Python script can spoof its user agent so that the proxy see it as a regular browser.

For example, using the very good [request library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (but any HTTP library can do that):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.wikipedia.org/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'})
```

Comment: I've used requests library in my python program, and i've tried that too... but it didn't work. :/

Comment: Well I think you should investigate on the proxy options. As soon as your browser traffic can pass through it, you can too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if CORS is the only problem you are facing, you can use [jsonp](http://json-p.org/) to make a request.

Also to continue till end, you can add a `range header` from that `byte` to `-`. See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) or you can refer to [content-length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) response header to get the size of file.